# Terraform - How to use conditionally created resource's output in conditional operator?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a case where I have to create an aws_vpc resource if the user does not provide vpc id. After that I am supposed to create resources with that VPC.

Now, I am applying conditionals while creating an `aws_vpc` resource. For example, only create VPC if `existing_vpc` is false:

```
count                = "${var.existing_vpc ? 0 : 1}"
```

Next, for example, I have to create nodes in the VPC. If the `existing_vpc` is true, use the `var.vpc_id`, else use the computed VPC ID from `aws_vpc` resource.

But, the issue is, if `existing_vpc` is true, `aws_vpc` will not create a new resource and the ternary condition is anyways trying to check if the `aws_vpc` resource is being created or not. If it doesn't get created, terraform errors out.

An example of the error when using conditional operator on `aws_subnet`:

```
Resource 'aws_subnet.xyz-subnet' not found for variable 'aws_subnet.xyz-subnet.id'
```

The code resulting in the error is:

```
subnet_id = "${var.existing_vpc ? var.subnet_id : aws_subnet.xyz-subnet.id}"
```

If both things are dependent on each other, how can we create conditional resources and assign values to other configuration based on them?

Comment: The direct answer to your question is to use `null` in the upcoming 0.12 release. The indirect answer is that it sounds like the code conditionals and organization should be redone to avoid this issue, because that ternary for the `subnet_id` seems like it should be different.

Comment: Well, my provider currently does not support 0.12 as of now. So, I have to continue with 0.11.x. Any way I can make this work?

Answer (score 37):

You can access dynamically created modules and resources as follows

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = length(module.vpc) > 0 ? module.vpc[*].id : null
}
```

- If count = 0, output is null
- If count > 0, output is list of vpc ids

If **count = 1** and you want to receive a single vpc id you can specify:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = length(module.vpc) > 0 ? one(module.vpc).id : null
}
```

Comment: "ONE" function is available only in Terraform v0.15 and later.

Answer (score 5):

The following example shows how to optionally specify whether a resource is created (using the conditional operator), and shows how to handle returning output when a resource is not created. This happens to be done using a module, and uses an `object` variable's element as a flag to indicate whether the resource should be created or not.

But to specifically answer your question, you can use the conditional operator as follows:

```
    output "module_id" {
       value = var.module_config.skip == true ? null : format("%v",null_resource.null.*.id)
    }
```

And access the output in the calling main.tf:

```
module "use_conditionals" {
    source = "../../scratch/conditionals-modules/m2" # << Change to your directory
    a = module.skipped_module.module_id # Doesn't exist, so might need to handle that.
    b = module.notskipped_module.module_id
    c = module.default_module.module_id
}
```

Full example follows. NOTE: this is using terraform v0.14.2

---

```
# root/main.tf
provider "null" {}

module "skipped_module" {
    source = "../../scratch/conditionals-modules/m1" # << Change to your directory
    module_config = { 
        skip = true         # explicitly skip this module.
        name = "skipped" 
    }
}

module "notskipped_module" {
    source = "../../scratch/conditionals-modules/m1" # << Change to your directory
    module_config = { 
        skip = false        # explicitly don't skip this module.
        name = "notskipped"
    }
}

module "default_module" {
    source = "../../scratch/conditionals-modules/m1" # << Change to your directory
    # The default position is, don't skip. see m1/variables.tf
}

module "use_conditionals" {
    source = "../../scratch/conditionals-modules/m2" # << Change to your directory
    a = module.skipped_module.module_id
    b = module.notskipped_module.module_id
    c = module.default_module.module_id
}

# root/outputs.tf
output skipped_module_name_and_id {
    value = module.skipped_module.module_name_and_id
}

output notskipped_module_name_and_id {
    value = module.notskipped_module.module_name_and_id
}

output default_module_name_and_id {
    value = module.default_module.module_name_and_id
}
```

---

the module

---

```
# m1/main.tf
resource "null_resource" "null" {
    count = var.module_config.skip ? 0 : 1 # If skip == true, then don't create the resource.

    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<EOT
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        echo "null resource, var.module_config.name: ${var.module_config.name}"
EOT
    }
}

# m1/variables.tf
variable "module_config" {
    type = object ({ 
        skip = bool, 
        name = string 
    })
    default = {
        skip = false
        name = "<NAME>"
        }
}

# m1/outputs.tf
output "module_name_and_id" {
   value = var.module_config.skip == true ? "SKIPPED" : format(
      "%s id:%v",
      var.module_config.name, 
      null_resource.null.*.id
   )
}

output "module_id" {
      value = var.module_config.skip == true ? null : format("%v",null_resource.null.*.id)
}
```

---

Comment: Can you confirm that there is a mistype on your example in "module "use_conditionals", you source from 'm2'... Do you mean m1 ?

Answer (score 1):

The current answers here are helpful when you are working with more modern versions of terraform, but as noted by OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257169/terraform-how-to-use-conditionally-created-resources-output-in-conditional-op#comment99132096_56257169) they do not work when you are working with terraform < 0.12 (If you're like me and still dealing with these older versions, I am sorry, I feel your pain.)

See the relevant issue from the terraform project for [more info](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15165) on why the below is necessary with the older versions.

but to avoid link rot, I'll use the OPs example subnet_id argument using the answers in the github issue.

```
subnet_id = "${element(compact(concat(aws_subnet.xyz-subnet.*.id, list(var.subnet_id))),0)}"
```

From the inside out:

1. [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#concat-list1-list2-) will join the splat output list to list(var.subnet_id) -- per the background link 'When count = 0, the "splat syntax" expands to an empty list'
2. [compact](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#compact-list-) will remove the empty item
3. [element](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#element-list-index-) will return your var.subnet_id only when compact recieves the empty splat output.

Answer (score 0):

As of Terraform v0.15 the best solution is actually:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = one(module.vpc[*].id)
}
```

This uses the [splat expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) to create a list of ids. If no VPC was created the list will be empty. The [one() function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one) will then convert this to either the first element of the list or null.