# How to create string output with splat operator in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am creating several `count` - based ELBs with `terraform`.

e.g.

```
resource "aws_elb" "webserver_example" {
  count           = var.create_webserver
  name            = var.name
  subnets         = data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.elb[count.index].id]
}
```

I therefore want to be able to get as outputs their http endpoints.

These outputs I assume shoul be strings, and their should somehow incorporate each `elb`'s dns name.

However the following approach using splat, does not work

```
output "url" {
  value = "http://${aws_elb.webserver_example.*.dns_name}:${var.elb_port}"
}
```

```
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on outputs.tf line 2, in output "url":
│    2:   value = "http://${aws_elb.webserver_example.*.dns_name}:${var.elb_port}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_elb.webserver_example is empty tuple
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
╵
```

Is there a way to print multiple count-based strings?

Comment: Do you actually want a count here or do you just want to not have it error if you have `create_webserver = false`? If you just want the latter then does https://stackoverflow.com/a/65323592/2291321 answer your question?

Comment: I want to be able to create from 0 to multiple instances of the ELB and output their http endpoints

Comment: Can you update your question to include something a bit more representative then please?

Comment: rephrased my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I was able to infer from just the code you provided, your `var.create_webserver` will have different count values (e.g. >= 0). The answer to your specific question is in this code block:

```
output "url" {
  value = [
    for dns_name in aws_elb.webserver_example.*.dns_name :
    format("http://%s:%s", dns_name, var.elb_port)
  ]
}
```

However, be sure you introduce some way to make the names of your Security Groups and ELBs different, because that will be your next error. For example, `name = "${var.name}-${count.index}"`.

Once you get to that point, you will have output that looks like this:

```
Outputs:

url = [
  "http://so-0-2118247212.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443",
  "http://so-1-1137510015.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "aws_elb" "webserver_example" {
  count           = var.create_webserver
  name            = var.name
  subnets         = data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.elb[count.index].id]
}

output "url" {
  value = aws_elb.webserver_example.*.dns_name
}
```